# Xcode 8.3 and Swift 3 :Display Image in Cell in UICollectionView from URL fetched and Stored in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, afnetworking, sdwebimage

I have Fetched Data From Web service using the Following Piece of Code

```
func ws_GetRelatedRresourcePath(_ RresourceId:Int, arrRresourceIDs:NSArray) {
    let refID = arrRresourceIDs.object(at: RresourceId);

    AlbumModel.getRelatedRresourcePath(parameters: refID as AnyObject?) { (responseObject,success) in

        if(success){
            let tempResp = responseObject;

            if tempResp != nil  {
                self.arrRelatedRresource.add(tempResp!)
            }else {
            if(responseObject != nil){
                print(responseObject!);
            }
        }

        if RresourceId < arrRresourceIDs.count - 1 {
            self.ws_GetRelatedRresourcePath(RresourceId + 1, arrRresourceIDs: arrRresourceIDs);
        }else{
            print("Done.")
            self.collectionSameSeriesMedia.reloadData();
            self.setupMediaView();
            AppUtils.stopLoading();
        }
    }
```

By Implementing This I am getting the URL of Image Stored in the NSmutableArray Named arrRelatedRresource.

I am Passing this Array to the cellForItemAt as Follows

```
let cell = collectionSameSeriesMedia.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SameSeriesMediaIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MediaDetailsCollectionViewCell

        var strImagePath = arrRelatedRresource[indexPath.row] as! String
        print(strImagePath);
        strImagePath = (strImagePath as AnyObject).replacingOccurrences(of: "\\" , with: "");
         strImagePath = strImagePath.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"" , with: "");
        print(strImagePath)
        cell.imgSameSeriesMedia.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: strImagePath))
        return cell
```

**Edited :- (Solved)**

The problem was with The array in which it was Storing the Data. The array was storing the URL with an Extra **""**.
I solved this Silly issue by adding following line of code in it.

```
  strImagePath = strImagePath.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"" , with: "");
```

The issue was Solved by this.

Comment: When someone asks you for code or clarification, you need to [edit] that information into your question. Do not post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use sd_setImage with completion handler and check if ur getting a nil image.

```
var strImagePath = arrRelatedRresource[indexPath.row] as! String
 strImagePath = strImagePath.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

    let url = URL(string: strImagePath)
if let url = url{
   NSLog("url = %@",url)
    cell.imgSameSeriesMedia.sd_setImage(with: url as URL!, placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions(), completed: { (image: UIImage?, error: Error?, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: URL?) in
                        if image != nil{
                           cell.imgSameSeriesMedia.backgroundcolor = UIColor.green
                        }
                        else{
                          cell.imgSameSeriesMedia.backgroundcolor = UIColor.blue
                        }
                    })
}
```

Comment: I m Getting Blue background i.e nil image. I also Tried  print(cell.imgSameSeriesMedia.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:strImagePath as! String), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholderImage"))).  But the Result was ().  Can You suggest some improvement in my code.

Comment: I also tried. let url = URL(string: strImagePath as! String) ----  print(url!) . the app got Crashed with Bad Instruction.

Comment: That means your url is nil. You should try encoding url.                                url = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore please share one urlString example that you are getting in response. When you are trying to convert strImagePath to url it becomes nil

Comment: when i 
Print(strImagePath). the result is something like this "http://192.168.1.122/gallery/filestore/3/2_3c89ad1dcf88c1c/32_e185143eb8f72cb.jpg"..

Comment: I Executed You Updated Code. It Prints the url like this %22http:%5C/%5C/192.168.1.122%5C/gallery%5C/filestore%5C/3%5C/0_7719dd258338f34%5C/30_904f7ec0d65f8fb.jpg%22 and the result is still the Blue background i.e image is nil.

Comment: Got the probelm.... your strImagePath starts and ends with " character.    var strImagePath = ""http://192.168.1.122/gallery/filestore/3/2_3c89ad1dcf88c1c/32_e185143eb8f72cb.jpg"". Somewhere in your code you are adding " at the start and end of urlpath

Comment: It should be var strImagePath = "xyz" not ""xyz""

Comment: It is in the Format "Xyz" .See my Question I have copied the output of Print(strImagePath) .  "http://192.168.1.122/gallery/filestore/3/2_3c89ad1dcf88c1c/32_e185143eb8f72cb.jpg". I have not added any "" in the code